# sqlalchemy relationship with and_ conjunction not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Developing Python app using `sql-alchemy`.
Have following two classes:

```
class Meter(Base):
    __tablename__: str = 'meter'
    __table_args__ = ({'schema': SCHEMA})
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(1024), nullable=True)
    service_id = Column(BigInteger,
                        ForeignKey(Service.id, name='meter_service_id_fk'),
                        nullable=False)

    service = relationship('Service',
                           primaryjoin="and_(Meter.service_id == Service.id, Service.name == 'metering')",
                           lazy='selectin', viewonly=False
                           )
```

and

```
class Service(Base):
    __tablename__: str = 'service'
    __table_args__ = ({'schema': SCHEMA})
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(1024), nullable=True)
```

So the problem is that `primaryjoin="and_(Meter.service_id == Service.id, Service.name == 'metering')"` in `Meter` class not working and it joins to all rows in `Service` class and ignores `Service.name == 'metering'` condition.
Doing as described [in manual](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html).

Any idea what is wrong with my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The join condition in the relationship conditions which rows from the `Service` table are loaded when `Meter` is queried.  It does not condition which rows from `Meter` are loaded.

If you want to load only those `Meter`s which have a "metering" `Service` you will need to apply a `WHERE` condition:

```py
# SQLAlchemy 1.x style
meters = session.query(Meter).join(Service).filter(Service.name == 'metering')

# SQLAchemy 1.4 / 2.0 style
meters = session.execute(
         select(Meter).join(Meter.service).where(Service.name == "metering")
)
```